# Motion Editor showed "Version ConstraintLayout library must be version 2.0.0 beta 3 or later" in android Studio 4.0.1 and constraintLayout 2.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-motionlayout

I have already read this question but it does not help
[Motion editor not working in Android studio 4.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307452/motion-editor-not-working-in-android-studio-4-0-1)

Here is the dependency I used

`androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0`

And my android studio version is 4.0.1

When I restarted Android Studio it showed the motion editor correctly but when I try to edit it, I got this error "Version ConstraintLayout library must be version 2.0.0 beta 3 or later"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just upgrade the library to version 2.0.1.

Comment: When I upgrade the version and then restart AS, it works :)